# Is this still Cress?

Tags: identification

I bought some Cress a while ago to go in Egg Mayo sandwhiches. I decided to plant some of the Cress and now it's morphed into something that doesn't resemble Cress anymore.

I've researched types of Cress from different countries but none of them resemble the Cress that's now growing.

Can anyone shed some light on if this is actually Cress or if something else is now growing? (It's the middle plant in the photo). Is this plant still edible?

[image: photo of the Cress]

Comment: when you say you bought some cress, do you mean already growing in a little container from the supermarket, known as salad cress in the UK, or do you mean seeds?

Comment: It was bought from the supermarket already growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confirmed you bought cress from the supermarket, ready for use, growing in its container.

There are several varieties of the plant called cress, and the differences are often not apparent in the small containers with just the cotyledons showing, its only as they grow and get several leaves that you can tell the variety. Usually, the plant used in those small containers is Lepidium sativum, sometimes known as Garden or Salad Cress. All are edible, but the one in your image that looks most like salad cress is the one with the heavily dissected leaves in the top pot, left hand side of your photograph. More information and an image of more mature cress here https://www.growveg.com/guides/how-to-grow-cress-for-grownups/